# Dividing an array by an array column in R

Tags: arrays, r

My data is the following:

```
print(xr)
[1] 1.1235685 1.0715964 0.2043725 4.0639341

> class(xr)
[1] "array"
```

I'm trying to divide the values of all the columns in my array by the value given by the 1st column (ie, 1.1235685). The resulting array would be:

```
1.000 0.953 0.181 3.616
```

How would I do this in R, given my R-data object type? The columns do not have names, because of the datatype. (If there's a way I can assign a column names before dividing them, then that's even better.)

I'm new to R, so apologies for the simple question.

Thank you.

Comment: 1) Can you provide the data? 2) an array is read as a vector when you subset it, if you do not format it before. You need to you format it according to its dims first.

Comment: `a <- array(c(1.1235685, 1.0715964, 0.2043725, 4.0639341)); a / a[1]`

Comment: `xr / xr[1]` will do it. And, `round(xr / xr[1], 3)` will give you values with 3 decimals.

Comment: @DamianoFantini. What do you mean by "you need to you format it according to its dims first"? The data I provided is all the data I have. It's the result of creating an empty array called "xr" using xr<-array(). I then population the array using a canned arithmetic function.

Comment: @StatsScared. Arrays are R data objects which can store data in more than two dimensions (for example multi-channel imaging data are imported as arrays). I assumed that you were using an array because you had more than a vector to store in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people already answered this in the comments, but I'll try to provide a more comprehensive one. The code to do what you want is pretty simple.

```
xr <- array(data = c(1.1235685, 1.0715964, 0.2043725, 4.0639341))
xr/xr[1]
```

However, if you created that array with only one dimension, I would recommend you use a numeric vector instead, which has no "dim" attribute. You'd create it as follows:

```
xr <- c(1.1235685, 1.0715964, 0.2043725, 4.0639341))
xr/xr[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you mind explaining why using a numeric vector is better in this case?

Comment: It's just a simpler class. In an array, if you change the 'dim' attribute, you can end up with a 2d, 3d or Nd array. With a vector, you know it will always have only one dimension.